# WCF: Create public WCF service to response data in JSON: Simple Example

Tags: .net, asp.net, wcf, wcf-client

As I am working on one `web application`, I want to create one `WCF service to expose` our system data.

My service will receive `input data`(params) and based on that, I want to `response data using JSON format` to our customer/caller.

I also wants to `create public URL for my WCF service`, so our customer/caller `can invoke it`.

Could you please `suggest tutorial OR example` for how could `I achieve this by WCF`.

Thanks in Advance.

**PS: Want a simple tutorial/example for how I can create a WCF service that returns JSON response.**